# Is it good practice to up vote correct answers to duplicate questions?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I've noticed on Stack Overflow (and this is probably true for other SE sites) that I often run into duplicate questions that were never flagged. A lot of these questions are answered, often correctly and sometimes it's really a great answer. So I'm wondering, is it good practice to up vote these answers?

In the privileges section the following is stated.

> Whenever you encounter a question or answer that you feel is
>   especially useful, vote it up!

Now this may be true to the answer in question, but should I up vote these good questions? After all, they are to a duplicate question, and the original question may have a similar good answer.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> is it good practice to up vote these answers?

Sure - a good answer is a good answer. The questions may end up being merged, which still makes the answers useful and correct.

Having duplicate questions is a good thing as different people will search using different terms. Having duplicates means there are better chances for people to find an answer to their question (of course, this excludes exact copy-paste questions). If the question is closed a a duplicate, a link to the duplicate/s will come up at the top of the question, leading the users to more answers.

> should I up vote these good questions?

Same answer - a good question is a good question and deserved being upvoted. You should still cast a vote to close as a duplicate. If it does get closed as such, links to the duplicate/s will be posted at the top of the question for others to follow, so a useful thing in itself.